# How to parallely train multiple keras models?

Tags: python, for-loop, tensorflow, keras, parallel-processing

I have 100 different datasets. I want to train a keras model 100 times and during each time, a single dataset was used. Here is my code

```
from keras.layers import Input, Dense
from keras.models import Model
from time import time
import numpy as np

time_begin = time()

features = {}
labels = {}
In = {}
dense_1 = {}
dense_1_output = {}
dense_2 = {}
dense_2_output = {}
model = {}

num_model = 100
num_data = 1000
input_dim = 5
for i in range(num_model):
    # generate 100 different datasets, the i-th dataset is features[i], labels[i]
    features[i] = np.random.normal(0, 1, (num_data, input_dim))
    labels[i] = np.sum(features[i], axis=1)

    In[i] = Input((input_dim,), name='input_'+str(i))
    dense_1[i] = Dense(units=20, activation='sigmoid', name='dense_1_'+str(i))
    dense_1_output[i] = dense_1[i](In[i])
    dense_2[i] = Dense(units=1, activation='linear', name='dense_2_'+str(i))
    dense_2_output[i] = dense_2[i](dense_1_output[i])

    # build and train 100 models over 100 different datasets
    model[i] = Model(In[i], dense_2_output[i])
    model[i].compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mean_squared_error')
    model[i].fit(features[i], 
                 labels[i], 
                 batch_size=64, 
                 epochs=5, 
                 verbose=2,
                 validation_split=.2)

print('The code runs {} minutes.'.format((time()-time_begin)/60.0))
```

The for-loop `for i in range(num_model)` will be executed orderly.  Can anyone teach me that how to improve this and train them in a parallel way?

Comment: why not merge the files into 1 dataset first?

Comment: @Alex Thanks for your reply. The 100 datasets generated in the code is just for convenient to illustrate my problem. In fact, the 100 datasets are sampled from 100 different systems. So it is a little bit improper to merge them all into one file and then train only one model over one dataset.

Comment: it is strange to use different datasets. For clarity, I would rephrase it as 'one dataset, spread over 100 files'.

Comment: @Alex ^_^ I hope there is a method to help save the training time.